# Finding all distinct values from single column of an attribute table with GDAL

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal

I am working with GDAL and modify ESRI shapefiles with it. I am searching a possibility how to find all distince values from a single column of an attribute table with GDAL (Python). In SQL it would be `SELECT DISTINCT field FROM table`. I found how to do that in ArcPy but I prefer to use open source software.

Furthermore, I was thinking about iterating through the column (which are different classes) and calculate their area. Anybody an idea?

```py
for i in range(layer.GetFeatureCount()):
  feature = layer.GetFeature(i)
  #here somehow iterate/sort through "feature.GetField("classes")"
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `ExecuteSQL` on an OGR data source to return a new layer. E.g.

```
from osgeo import ogr
ogr_ds = ogr.Open('table.shp')
sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT field FROM table'
layer = ogr_ds.ExecuteSQL(sql)
for i, feature in enumerate(layer):
    print('{0}: {1}'.format(i, feature.GetField(0)))
```

Note that there is no geometry in the layer, since it wasn't part of the SQL query.

Much more information for the default "OGRSQL" dialect [is described here](https://gdal.org/user/ogr_sql_dialect.html). An alternative [SQLite SQL dialect](https://gdal.org/user/sql_sqlite_dialect.html) can be enabled by using `ogr_ds.ExecuteSQL(sql, dialect='SQLITE')`.

Comment: How the selection between OGR SQL and SQLite SQL dialects is done with python? Both dialects have some features which are missing from the other.

Answer (score 9):

With the SQLite dialect GDAL/OGR supports everything that is supported by SQLite http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html and Spatialite http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html.

You can demonstrate how to get an ordered list of distinct attribute values with ogrinfo. For sure the same functionality is available also from python.

```
ogrinfo test.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "select distinct attribute_1 from test order by attribute_1"
INFO: Open of 'test.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: None
Feature Count: 342
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
attribute_1: String (0.0)
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  attribute_1 (String) = abc

OGRFeature(SELECT):1
  attribute_1 (String) = bca

OGRFeature(SELECT):2
  attribute_1 (String) = cba
```

Similarly you can get the sum of feature areas grouped by classes with

```
ogrinfo test.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "select attr_1, sum(area(geometry)) from test group by attr_1 order by attr_1"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i search something in Python as mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know python. Take this as encouragement, you can do it by calling SQL from python.

Answer (score 5):

I like Mike Ts response (+1!).

However, if you want to stick with what you have and not use sql, here's another way:

```
feature = layer.GetNextFeature()
field_vals = []
while feature:
  field_vals.append(feature.GetFieldAsString('FIELD_NAME'))
  feature = layer.GetNextFeature()

#use set to get distinct field_vals
print set(field_vals)
```

note that 'GetFieldAsString' may not be what you wish to use.

Answer (score 0):

Simple one-line, no-sql solution: (simplified from the answer of @user1269942)
`set([feature[field_name] for feature in layer])`